# Can not use LINQ Queries in Indexer Get Method

Tags: c#

Are there any limitation for indexers in C#?

Can not use a LINQ in `get` method:

```
'User' does not contain a definition for 
'Id' and no accessible extension method 'Id' accepting a 
first argument of type 'User' could be found
(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Weird, because outside of this repository I am able to use LINQ. Like
`User user = users.First(x => x.Id == id);`

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Uri Avatar { get; set; }
}

public class MockRepository<User>
{
    private List<User> _users = new List<User>() { ... };

    public User this[int index]
    {
        get { return _users.First(x => x.Id == index); }
                                       ^^^^
    }
}
```

Comment: that object has double quotes. Is it supposed to be json? Your linq seems to be working it just doesn't seem to find what you want it to find.

Comment: It is escaped json and valid. Just ignore it.

Comment: `public class MockRepository : User` would work.

Comment: Could it be that you have two classes `User` in your app?

Comment: No, this is a very simple app.

Comment: Can you also post the object please?

Comment: You should use an Interface, `IUser`, that `User` implements, then you can have `public class MockRepository<IUser>`.

Comment: You are declaring a generic type named _User_ with `MockRepository`. This shadows the name of the actual `User` class inside the body of `MockRepository`. You can try this by calling `User` with its full name (YourNamespace.User) inside `MockRepository` and see the difference.

Answer (score 3):

You are refering to your Generic Type `User` instead of the class `User`. Also you need a [Type Contraint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters), if you need to use the User properties.

```
public class MockRepository<TUser> where TUser : User
{
    private List<TUser> _users = new List<TUser>() { ... };

    public User this[int index]
    {
        get { return _users.First(x => x.Id == index); }
    }
}
```

This is why we always have the prefix `T` on Type parameters ;)

Comment: Yes, the big problem here was, that the generic type parameter used has the same name as an exisiting class.

Comment: Allow me to add further explanation: what happened was that the generic name `User` shadowed the name of the `User` class within the `MockRepository` class body. You (OP) wrote the placeholder of the generic type in  `MockRepository` (conventionally indicated as `T` instead), not the `User` class name. This makes `List<User>` a list of a generic type indicated as _User_, not a list of objects of type `User`.